# A query is taking 9 hours to import 1.900.000 rows from Database A to Amazon Quicksight

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

[image: AMAZON QUICKSIGHT HISTORY]

**Log History:**
2020/04/13 22:12:36 Completed
Ingestion completed in **9 hours 22 minutes 1 seconds.**

Rows dropped: 0, Rows ingested: 1916870

Manual, Full refresh

```
SELECT
       uc.name,
       u.username       AS usuario,
       u.firstname,
       u.lastname,
       c.fullname       AS titulo_bit,
       CASE
           WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ci.id
                       FROM mdl_certificate_issues ci
                                LEFT JOIN mdl_certificate ce ON (ci.certificateid = ce.id)
                       WHERE ci.userid = u.id
                         AND ce.course = c.id)
               THEN 100
           ELSE
               ROUND(COUNT(cmc.completionstate) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                         FROM mdl_course_modules
                                                         WHERE course = cm.course
                                                           AND deletioninprogress IS false
                                                           AND completion IS true))
           END          AS porcentaje_avance_bit,
       uai.company_area AS area_old,
       u.department,
       u.address,
       u.institution,
       muca.name        AS area,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(cmc.timemodified) as course_progress_time

FROM mdl_course_modules_completion cmc
         LEFT JOIN mdl_course_modules cm ON (cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id)
         LEFT JOIN mdl_course c ON (cm.course = c.id)
         LEFT JOIN mdl_user u ON (cmc.userid = u.id)
         LEFT JOIN mdl_u_user_additional_info uai ON (u.id = uai.mdl_user_id)
         LEFT JOIN mdl_u_company_area muca ON uai.company_area_id = muca.id
         RIGHT JOIN mdl_u_company uc ON (uai.mdl_u_company_id = uc.id)

WHERE cm.deletioninprogress IS false
  AND cm.completion IS true
  AND cmc.completionstate != 0
  AND u.deleted IS FALSE
  AND c.visible IS TRUE

GROUP BY cm.course, cmc.userid, uc.name, uai.company_area, muca.id,  FROM_UNIXTIME(cmc.timemodified)
ORDER BY usuario, course_progress_time desc
```

Comment: Share your table structure, and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT` for this query.

Comment: Is the query taking that time, or the import process? You could test this by selecting the data into a new table (`CREATE TABLE AS`) and timing how long it takes. Then, import the data from that table and time how long it takes. This will help identify whether the slowness is related to the query or the import process.